# Mongoose and Nodejs get the name of a user by there ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose and couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

I have a user schema like this:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    writer: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    producer: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})
```

And I want to get someone name by their `_id`

I have this: `Users.findById(posts.userID).schema.obj.name` but it obviously doesn't return a name, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findById` returns [a single document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) containing the actual values for the properties you've defined in your schema. So if you're just interested in getting the name from the resulting document you can do:

```
 const user = await Users.findById(posts.userID);
 const name = user.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any request to mongo via mongoose is asynchronus.
So .findById method return promise-like object.
You need to wait for result via one of three ways:

1. Pass callback function like

```
Users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  console.log(user.name);
});
```

2. Use .then() like with promise

```
Users.findById(id).then((user) => {
  console.log(user.name);
});
```

3. Use async/await:

```
async function getUser(id) {
   const user = await Users.findById(id);
   console.log(user.name);
};
```